# What does "int* const* num" mean?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between const int*, const int * const, int const *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const)

I was reading FLTK code when I bumped into this line of code:

```
Fl_Widget*const* a = array();
```

here is the actual code:

```
Fl_Widget*const* Fl_Group::array() const {
    return children_ <= 1 ? (Fl_Widget**)(&array_) : array_;
}

int Fl_Group::find(const Fl_Widget* o) const {
    Fl_Widget*const* a = array();
    int i; for (i=0; i < children_; i++) if (*a++ == o) break;
    return i;
}
```

Now I'm wondering what is the type of pointer variable `a`. Are `Fl_Widget*const* a = array();` and `Fl_Widget** const a = array();` equal?

Comment: There is an existing post that covers this (and many more combinations of pointer and const): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const

Comment: You can use the [right-left rule](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html) to "deciper" this.

Comment: Use [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int*const*+a).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read it right-to-left:

```
Fl_Widget      *            const            *              a
          "pointer to" <- "constant" <- "pointer to"  <- "a is"
```

Which sums up to "`a` is a pointer to constant pointer to `Fl_Widget`".

Declarations in `VAR a: POINTER TO CONST POINTER TO Fl_Widget` style would have been a bit more clear, but C++ drags his variable declaration syntax from C, and C was all about expressions, not data types. Heck, it didn't even have `const` word, so you didn't have to think about it, and `int *a, b` was obviously deciphered as "`*a` is `int`, and `b` is `int`".